# i18next mapping en-US locale to en namespace folder/file

Tags: node.js, internationalization, i18next, i18next-http-backend, i18next-browser-languagedetector

Sorry if I am not asking this question correctly, currently, our system uses i18next with the `i18next-http-backend` and `i18next-browser-languagedetector`. The browser, using `i18next-browser-languagedetector` returns `en-US` when the browser is using an English locale setting. However the nodejs app is set up with the `i18next-http-backend` in a way where the translations are set up in english for `/public/locales/en/language.json`. Now the problem is, the i18next package relies on the fallback language because, `en-US` does not map to the  en (`/public/locales/en/`) namespace/folder location.

I know, it would be very simple enough to just rename the folder or simple enough to change the fallback language to en.

But I feel like there is a way to map this or an alternative way that i can't figure out and can't find in the docs so I am wondering if its possible, that when the languagedetector detects en-US locale, it will map to the /public/locales/en/ location

any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add: `nonExplicitSupportedLngs: true,` in the i18next config file, for example:

```
i18next
    ...
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .init({
        supportedLngs: ['en', 'es'],
        nonExplicitSupportedLngs: true, //support language variation
        ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, set the `load` option to `'languageOnly'`: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options#languages-namespaces-resources
[image]